# javascript prompt- how to show the ok/cancel button in arabic text

Tags: javascript, prompt

I have used a js prompt. The message and default value shown in Arabic , but OK/Cancel button shown in English, How to change the OK/Cancel button in to Arabic

My java script is

```
var enter_name ='<fmt:message key="enter.name"/>';
var _name ='<fmt:message key="default.name"/>';

prompt(enter_name,_name);
```

Properties file 
Arabic

```
enter.name=أدخل اسم المستخدم
default.name=اسم المستخدم
```

English

```
enter.name=Enter Username
default.name=Username
```

I have tried with jPrompt , changed the `jquery.alerts.js` Ok/Cancel button changed to Arabic and jPrompt displayed it correctly means it shown in Arabic. But the problem is when we use the jPrompt ,it execute the next line of code before clicking the Ok/Cancel button.I don't  need to execute next line of code before clicking the OK/Cancel button. That s why I choose prompt , but I don't know how to change the OK/Cancel button caption into arabic.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. `prompt` is a browser API that uses the browser chrome locale - ie, the "OK" and "CANCEL" will be in the client browser's language.

Comment: Oh I see thanks for your quick response. can I prevent the next line  execution  before clicking the OK/Cancel button While using the jPrompt?

Answer (score 0):

the javascript prompt is not in your control. IE on windows follows Operating system language for the prompt message . i.e. as it uses messagebox Win32 API call. non native browsers Google chrome and Firefox uses Browser language settings . Its like browsers might follow OS language or browser language . Refer :- [set browser language](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-priorities.en.php).